# html table row "id" field onclick javascript fetch value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html I have:

```
 <div align="center">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="table">

                <div class="row header">
                    <div class="cell">Select No</div>
                    <div class="cell">Id</div>
                    <div class="cell">Name</div>


                </div>
                <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}" varStatus="status">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell">${status.index + 1}</div>
                        <%-- <div class="cell">${student.u_id}</div> --%>

                        <div class="cell">
                            <a href="edit?id=${student.u_id}" onclick="return getData(this);">${student.u_id}</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cell">${student.name}</div>


                    </div>
                </c:forEach>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
function getData(element) {
        var ID = $(element).attr("u_id");

        var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var tds=o.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for(a in tds){
            inputs[a].value=tds[a].innerHTML;
        }


        console.log(ID);

        return false;
    }
```

My requirement:

Here I am displaying student list data into html table .
I want  after clicking **id** field it will call javascript and in console get the value of the id. But I am getting **undefiend** value in console.
what I am doing wrong??

Comment: There's no u_id attribute in your link element.

Comment: There is no u_id attribute in your anchor tag. You can extract the href (attribute) value and split the string to get value after =(equal symbol)

Answer (score 0):

`ID` selector supposed to be unique, but in your case you are assigning same `ID` to multiple element inside a loop which is wrong. Use `Class`  selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `u_id` attribute in your HTML code, only in the values you use in your EL expression `${....u_id}`.

Those attributes will be replaced  (as expected) by their actual values in the HTML, so if you need to retrieve them via javascript, you have to assign them also to another HTML attribute, or pass them in your `onclick` invocation.

With the current HTML code, you may read the value from the *content* of the `<a>` tag, but adding an attribute would be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ?

Comment: If I use this I am getting same value every time.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
<a href="edit?id=${student.u_id}" onclick="return getData(this);">${student.u_id}</a>
```

you have no `u_id` attribute, instead change it to

```
<a href="edit?id=${student.u_id}" onclick="return getData(this);" u_id="{student.u_id}">${student.u_id}</a>
```

Comment: Inspect element and check if u_id is attached to element or not